# Logstash Error - No config files found: logstash.conf. Can you make sure this path is a logstash config file?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

With logstash version 5.2.1 on Windows 10, I've created and saved a configuration file in the same directory as logstash.  However, when I run logstash -f logstash.conf from the command line I am getting the following error:

> [LogStash::Runner] INFO  logstash.agent - No config files found in
>   path {:path=>"C:/logstash-5.2.1/bin/logstash.conf"} [LogStash::Runner]
>   ERROR logstash.agent - failed to fetch pipeline configuration
>   {:message=>"No config files found: logstash.conf. Can you make sure
>   this path is a logstash config file?"}

I've done some searching and can't find a solution that fixes this issue.  Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you've placed your `conf` file in some other directory within `Logstash`, whereas `Logstash` is looking for the file within the **bin** folder.

Try moving your **logstash.conf** file within the *logstash* bin (`C:/logstash-5.2.1/bin/`) folder and then try executing the query (`logstash.bat -f logstash.conf`).